# How to read 2 columned csv files and plot colums as x vs y values

Tags: python, csv, pandas, matplotlib

I am a total newbie in programming, but I would like to use it to enhance my data Analysis. So I started to plot some csv files with python, but I just don´t manage to receive an x vs y plot.

Here is the Code I used so far:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('Phosphat_python.csv', delimiter=';')
plt.plot(df)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you need [`DataFrame.plot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html):

```
df.plot(x='col1', y='col2')
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':list('ABCD'),
                  'col2':[5,6,7,2]})
print (df)
  col1  col2
0    A     5
1    B     6
2    C     7
3    D     2

df.plot(x='col1', y='col2')
```

[image: graph]

Answer (score 1):

There will be multiple different ways to plot, but here is one clear example:
https://plot.ly/python/plot-data-from-csv/

What you're missing in your example, is you're not telling the program what you want your x & y to be. Some csv files might have a 100 different columns. So this example is great because it lets you visually see what is in the .csv file.